# AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener onOffsetChanged method is calling continously

Tags: android, android-appbarlayout, appbar

I am using [OnOffsetChangedListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener) interface to detect AppBarLayout's offset change. It working fine but the problem is [onOffsetChanged](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener#onOffsetChanged(android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout,%20int)) method is calling continuously. How can i stop this continuous call.

```
   offsetChangedListener = (appBarLayout, verticalOffset) -> {
        Log.i(TAG, "onOffsetChanged: verticalOffset: " + verticalOffset);

        //  Vertical offset == 0 indicates appBar is fully expanded.
        if (Math.abs(verticalOffset) > 200) {
            appBarExpanded = false;
             invalidateOptionsMenu();
        } else {
            appBarExpanded = true;
             invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the cause of the problem. Every time AppBarLayout's offset change that code is calling `invalidateOptionsMenu()` method. This `invalidateOptionsMenu()` method recreate `Menu` and cause AppBarLayout's offset change. So `onOffsetChanged` method is called again and again. I have removed `invalidateOptionsMenu()` method and change my logic to achieve my goal.

Comment: It happens also, if you are changing view layout params, or call requestLayout()

Comment: @KuvonchbekYakubov I'm also facing the same issue when changing layout params and calling requestLayout(). any solution for this?